# Convert a Duration into a String (or format a Duration as a String)

Tags: rust

How do I format a `std::time::Duration` object as a Rust String?

One possible useful example would be to produce an output string in the format of `[SECONDS, NANOSECONDS]`, although there could be other required formats.

How would one produce a string in this format?

Comment: What do you want the string to look like?

Comment: The `Duration` [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.Duration.html#formatting-duration-values) explicitly states why [`Display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html) is not implemented. You could just use the [`Debug`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Debug.html) output, if that is sufficient to you. The formatter  for debug output is the `?`, so you could create a string like this: `format!("{:?}", duration)`. Read more about formatting in Rust in the [`std::fmt`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html) module.

Comment: Are you sure you want `seconds.nanoseconds` and not `seconds.seconds_fraction`?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman If one is easier than the other, feel free to post either solution. Working with floats is usually not a good idea.

Comment: You may consider [formatting](https://time-rs.github.io/book/api/format-description.html) utilities from the `time` crate.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this particular problem using

```
let duration = std::time::Duration::from_secs(1); // etc
format!("[{}, {}]", duration.as_secs(), duration.subsec_nanos());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `Duration` as fractional seconds using [`as_secs_f64()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/time/struct.Duration.html#method.as_secs_f64).